# Format XML data with JavaScript in one file

Tags: javascript, css, xml, xslt

I want to convert a single XML file into a human-readable format by JavaScript.  Here is why:

1. Need to generate a human readable-document that is going to work everywhere. (Windows, Mac, Linux, iPhone, Android, Blackberry, etc.)
2. The information is coming out of a C++ data structure that I have defined.
3. Need to be able to include pictures.
4. This document would be sent as an email attachment once created.

I have looked into:

- XSLT: Can work as a single file, but only supported on the very newest mobile devices.
- CSS: I don't think the formatting is sophisticated enough to get what I need.
- PDF: Open source library would have to be included into environment. I would prefer not to do this if there is a good alternative.

So that is why I am looking at JavaScript.  But the first question is, can JavaScript format/display XML data that exists in the same file?  If so, how?

Comment: XML is just a markup language, it isn't intended to be viewed directly any more than HTML is. It also has no simple mechanism for embedding images or resources, HTML is better for that. Javascript can help you manipulate the document, it has nothing to do with display. If you want a device independent **document**, then PDF is a much better choice. There are a number of viewers for just about any device and it's supported natively in some environments.

Comment: I suspected I was going to be stuck using PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something strange. You can't use single JavaScript or CSS file as readable document with images. It's just impossible. Why you don't just use HTML? You can include CSS and JavaScript on HTML page and get almost any look and behaviour you want. HTML can be used as single file. Images can be included in HTML page using data:uri.

Answer (score 0):

It think server-side options (server-side XSLT for example) would be preferable, but if that's not available then you can parse an XML document in Javascript or JQuery.  For a simple example of how to do this using JQuery, see here:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/.  This example gets a "title" element from the XML and adds it to an HTML element with ID "somelement".

```
var xml = "";  // TODO get your xml here
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
var title = $xml.find("title");
$("#someelement").text(title);
```

If you're using plain Javascript, then you can parse the XML similarly to how you would HTML.  For example, let's say you have XML like this:

Then you can parse the XML document like so:

```
var items = myXml.getElementsByTagName('item');
var text = items[0].getAttribute('text');
$("#someelement").text(text);
```

Hope that helps...